# Jquery datepicker not showing in Android Webview. Works in native browser

Tags: android, webview, datepicker

I'm trying to embed an HTML page in a webview. The page has some jquery and javascript.  When an input field is clicked it brings out the jquery datepicker.   It works well in the native browser but, doesn't work in the webview.  I did set enableJavascript to true but still not showing. So I'm not sure how it works if opened in the native browser, but not if is in webview.    Am I missing anything? Any help is appreciated. This is my code:

```
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);        

    //Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    //Enable DOM Storage
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    //Enable Zoom
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    //I was adviced to place some of this to handle page navigation:
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    //other settings
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);


    //finally, load url
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.mycustomurl.com");
```

Comment: Add `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable Javascript in your webview...

like this,

```
WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

in your code, add this too..

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Oh ok, I tought I already had added this, but obviously I failed somehow.  Thanks Lal!